# Undesired reordering of keys in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have a quick question. When building an associative array key casting rules mean that strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8. (On the other hand "08" will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer.) See for example: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

The problem I have is that my keys are mixed integer and string .. meaning that when the associative array is built, all keys are reordered with numerical keys appear first before string. This is a sample of what I get in my console log:

```
...
2032: "9371.84"
2033: "9351.60"
2034: "9331.36"
2035: "9311.12"
ID: "1"
Misc1: "Russian Federation - Conventional"
Misc2: "RUS.Con1"
Misc3: "4"
Misc4: ""
...  etc.
```

How can I avoid this issue, so that the associative array does not re-order my keys?

As an FYI, this is how I generate my array in PHP:

```
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$experiment[] = $array;
};
```

Thank you for your time,
G.

Comment: `$experiment[]` generates only int keys.  Code and description make no sense.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Clearly it's output both int and string keys, as you can see that in the console log excerpt I have quoted. "ID" is a string, "Misc4" is a string, and 2032 is an int.

Comment: You need to post a `print_r($experiment)` or `var_dump($experiment)` and explain what parts of it are what and what you want them to be if that's the array you are talking about.  You talk about an "8" and "08", however it is nowhere in your console log.

Comment: Nowhere did I state "8" is a key in my array. This is an example provided by php.net to explain what I mean by key casting. The log excerpt I have shown is precisely that, an excerpt, as I doubt you need to see the 5,000 rows of data that I have. I think it is fairly obvious that the stuff preceding the colon is a [key] and that the stuff in quotes is the [value]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround for the issue I have found is to avoid the associative array structure. This is what my loop looks like now:

```
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$experiment[0] = array_keys($array);
$experiment[] = array_values($array);
};
```

The annoying thing is that `$experiment[0] = array_keys($array);` gets looped uneccessarily... but at least I get the result that I am looking for and the keys are not cast and re-ordered by the associative array.

If anybody knows how to avoid the unecessary looping for `$experiment[0]`, then please let me know :-)

Answer (score 1):

Adding an index to an array in PHP like this:

`$array[] = ['another array'];`

Will increment the indexes.

You can however specify a string for the key, or cast the integers to strings.

Comment: Hello Noah, thank you for your response. How would I either specify a string for the key or cast the integers to strings before they are reordered?

Comment: In PHP I believe to cast to an int, you put `int` in parentheses before the data.  Ex: `(int) $test` while `$test = 'test';`

Comment: Casting 'test' to an integer should return 0, but if you have a number in a string it should downcast it.